# Clicking drop down opens the wrong dtop down

Tags: javascript, html

I have a drop like this

```
<?php
            foreach($AllPosts as $post)
            {
                //echo $post['message'];
                echo "<br/>";


        ?>

        <div>
            <div class="dropdown">
            <div onclick='myFunction();' class="test dropbtn"></div>
              <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#home">Message</a>
                <a href="#about">Comment</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <p><?php echo $post['message']; ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>
```

and this is the javascript

```
<script>
        /* When the user clicks on the button, 
        toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        }

        // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
          if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

            var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
              var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
              if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
              }
            }
          }
        }
        </script>
```

when in the foreach the first one works fine but as soon as you click the second one it opens the first one again instead not not sure whats wrong

Comment: The id attribute should be unique on the page but you&amp;#39;re repeating it within the for loop. When getting the element calling document.getElementById(&amp;quot;myDropdown&amp;quot;).classList.toggle(&amp;quot;show&amp;quot;) it&amp;#39;s getting the first one in then DOM only. Sorry for the formatting, I'm writing this on the mobile app!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but you can try this one:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach($AllPosts as $post)
{
    //echo $post['message'];
    echo "<br/>";


    ?>

    <div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <div onclick='myFunction("myDropdown" + <?php echo $i?>);' class="test dropbtn">sdfgsd</div>
            <div id="myDropdown<?php echo $i?>" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#home">Message</a>
                <a href="#about">Comment</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p><?php echo $post; ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php $i++; } ?>



<script>
    /* When the user clicks on the button, 
     toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
    function myFunction(e) {
        document.getElementById(e).classList.toggle("show");
    }

    // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
            var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
            let i;
            for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

EDIT: Another way:

```
<?php
$AllPosts = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"];
$i = 0;
foreach($AllPosts as $post)
{
    //echo $post['message'];
    echo "<br/>";


    ?>

    <div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <div onclick='this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show")' class="test dropbtn">sdfgsd</div>
            <div id="myDropdown<?php echo $i?>" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#home">Message</a>
                <a href="#about">Comment</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p><?php echo $post; ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php $i++; } ?>



<script>
    // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
            var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
            let i;
            for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you not just pass &#39;this into the function instead of generating an id? Then you don&#39;t need to get the element from the DOM as you will already have it?

Comment: Pay attention that the ```id``` that I am sending to the function, is not of the current element (```this```), but of the next element. I can send an object by doing: ```myFunction(document.getElementById("myDropdown" + <?php echo $i?>));``` inside the ```onclick```.

Comment: @mdon88 Another way entered in edit - with ```this.nextElementSibling```.